# SwiftIconFont working well on simulator but not working on devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, icon-fonts

[SwiftIconFont pods framework](https://github.com/0x73/SwiftIconFont.git) working well on **simulator** but not working on **devices(iPhone & iPad)?** I have already added  **"Fonts provided by application"** section in **'info.plist'**.

[info.plist-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOZYK.png)

Comment: have you added those .ttf files into your app bundle?

Comment: bundle means info.plist right?

Comment: have you copied font into your project not just added reference.

Comment: no, the directory which contains all app data, for example in xcode where you can see your storyboard, view controllers, assets

Comment: i have added thru command 'pod install' and it has been added in project and it has been working on simulator

Comment: how you are trying to use those fonts?

Comment: i used to show in menu bar button like wherever i need image icons

Comment: https://github.com/Vaberer/Font-Awesome-Swift would work perfect for the above scenario